# How to link facebook icon used in bootstrap 4 with my actual facebook account or google mail with google mail icon?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to link an icon of Facebook with my Facebook account or google mail with Google mail account and LinkedIn account with LinkedIn icon while designing a webpage. So what is a line of code to use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using font-awesome this should work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9f03.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="link to my facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    <a href="link to my linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
    <a href="link to my gmail"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct answer.

Comment: Correct answer to the question I asked. Thanks for answering.